# How to pass the reference of a file to ref in OpenApi 3

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, micronaut

I have a ResponseEntity class which is of generic type

```
Class ResponseEntity<T> {
   Integer status;
   String message;
   T payload;
}
```

and i have a controller

```
//This is a declarative client which calls the internal-api for user data.
@Inject
UserRespositoryClient userRepoClient;

@ApiResponse(
    responseCode = "200",
    description = "Get a user by its id.",
    content = @Content(
        schema = @Schema(
            ref = "resources/schemas.yml#/components/schemas/User",
        ),
    )
)
@Get("user/{?userId}")
Single<ResponseEntity<?>> getUser(String userId) {
    return userRepoClient.getUserById(userId); 
}
```

Now, since we have passed the wild card (?) as the generic type in the ResponseEntity class. I
know its not good to pass the wild card type in the generics but the data which is from the
Internal-apis is dynamic so,i possibly couldn't create a model class and had to pass the wild card type but due this OpenApi could not create a schema which is obvious so, in the swagger ui at the schema sectionis displays an empty object like this

[swagger ui empty object example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFZ0j.png)

So, I created a schema.yml file where I have written the user-schema and
passed the reference of schema.yml file in schema ref like this:

```
schema = @Schema(
            ref = "resources/schemas.yml#/components/schemas/User",
)
```

My yml file directory looks like this
[Yml file directory example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPsyj.png)

but for some reason idk why the file is not getting located. No error occures. No message comes.
Nothing! Am I not passing the reference correctly or is there any other way to do this or
may be some better solution ?

btw I am using java --version: 11 and Micronaut --version: 2.5.4

Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't it component**s** (plural!) in your ref `"resources/schemas.yml#/components/schemas/User"`

Comment: My bad yes its components! but component or components, it shouldn't cause any problem right ?